# Indexed access operator overload for a MutableList member in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, operator-overloading, mutablelist

This is my scenario, I have several `MutableList` members, the first for storing `String` (called **sl**) and the rest for `Any` (called **objects**, **names**, ...), and I need to access the values in the **objects**, **names** and the rest through 2 ways:

1. **sl** through the index,
2. **objects**, **names** and the rest through the string value stored in **sl**,

Maybe an example is more clear:

```
var tmpListItem = myStringList.sl[0]  // read only for the sl list

myStringList.objects["keyname"] = "keyvalue"  // write and read for the rest
var tmpObj = myStringList.objects["keyname"]

myStringList.names["keyname"] = "keyvalue"
var tmpName = myStringList.names["keyname"]
```

I have been trying to overload the indexed access operator for a `MutableList`, but I get this error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected

This is my attempt so far:

```
data class StringList(val str: String) {
    val sl = mutableListOf<String>()
    val objects = mutableListOf<Any?>()
    val names = mutableListOf<Any?>()
    val values = mutableListOf<Any?>()
    val strings = mutableListOf<Any?>()

    public operator fun <E> MutableList<E>.set(k: String, value: Any?) {
        val t = sl.indexOf(k)
        objects[t] = value
    }
    operator fun <E> MutableList<E>.get(e: String): Any? {
        val t = sl.indexOf(e)
        return objects[t]
    }
}
```

Not sure if another implementation is more appropriate for my scenario, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use a Map or a List of Pairs?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you for the idea, but my explanation was incomplete, I need to handle others list, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

If you want to access them from outside, those `operator fun` shouldn't be extensions of `MutableList`.

```kotlin
data class StringList(val str: String) {
    val sl = mutableListOf<String>()
    val objects = mutableListOf<Any?>()

    operator fun set(k: String, value: Any?) {
        val t = sl.indexOf(k)
        objects[t] = value
    }
    operator fun get(e: String): Any? {
        val t = sl.indexOf(e)
        return objects[t]
    }
}
```

Now you can use them like so:

```kotlin
myStringList["keyname"] = "keyvalue"
var tmp = myStringList["keyname"]
```

**Details**

There are few things which I'd like to point out here:

1. Extensions functions declared **inside** a class can be accessed only in that class or in one of its subclasses, so you can still use your version (e.g. `myStringList.objects["keyname"]`) only if you are invoking that operator function **inside** `StringList`.
2. I think you should handle the case in which `indexOf()` returns `-1`, otherwise the functions `set` and `get` will throw an out-of-bounds exception.
3. If you can, consider to use a simple `Map<String, Any>` for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was incomplete, I've edited the question.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I saw it. That is a perfect use case for multiple `Map<String, Any?>`. Why can't you them?

Comment: Thank you very much @GiorgioAntonioli, I did that... now I have a `mutableListOf<String>` for the index access with numbers and several `mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()` for storing my objects.